# Image does not appear in Lotus Notes

Tags: html, image, lotus-notes

Got lotus notes version 8.5.

I need it to show html img properly.

```
<a target='_blank' href='http://www.foo.com'alt="external-link"><img class="document-url-image" src="http://foo.com/images/ico_globe.png" /></a>
```

Any ideas why i got red box instead of image?

Here's another one (with asp.net handler usage):

```
 <a href="http://redbull/WebPAC/lv/book.aspx?id=11"> 
    <img src="http://foo.com/bookthumbnail.axd?id=11" alt="book thumbnail" /> 
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine. It cached it. Pasted src in notes built-in browser and after reopening sent email it looks fine.